# Standard Real Estate Package

Tags: business, real-estate

I'm trying to get things in order to do real estate photography, and I'm trying to figure out some packages.

For real estate photography, what should a basic package consist of?

At the moment I'm thinking:

- Outside Front
- Entry
- Kitchen
- Bedroom
- Family/Living Room
- Bathroom

Comment: Seems like the better option is to offer a package of '5 photographs' or '10 photographs'.  Because if they have features in the backyard (pool, gazebo etc) you'll need to get that, or if they have a theater or a bar or a work room or a 5 car garage...

Comment: Who do you anticipate your clients will be? Seems like you'd want to know who you're marketing to before you build your packages. As I mentioned here: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8204/real-estate-equipment/8212#8212 my experience in real estate photography is specific to agents, and with that crowd, quantity of pictures was always far more important than quality...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should offer packages that consist of a number of photographs. They buy a 6-shot package and you give them the 6 shots of the rooms they want. You might want to shoot all the rooms and offer additional shots / differnt shots of the same rooms at a small additional.