# What type of wide-angled lens is the best option for photographing rooms in a hotel?

Tags: lens, wide-angle, architecture, real-estate, interior

We have a small B&B and would like ourself to do photos for frequent change on the website.

I am very good at photographing, technical aspects however are not my strongest side. I need to have better than an amateur camera with a wide-angle lens. What type/brand of camera and lens will be the optimal from the viewpoint of quality and price.

Comment: You're really talking about real estate photography.  See [this question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8204/what-equipment-is-necessary-preferred-for-real-estate-photography) that is very close.

Answer (score 6):

A semi fisheye or very wide angle may work for you, but you may well be better off using an edge-of-wideangle lens and panorama stitching or virtual tour software. Very wide angle lenses will invariably introduce what the eye/brain see as distortion. A panorame can be made to feel more normal even if it is effectively introducing distortions of its own (eg mapping time variant angular rotation on to a linear plane).

As one example, panorama software from Autostitch is free and marvellous, and commercial offerings using it add to it's basic functionality.
 Autostitch [**free download here**](http://www.cs.bath.ac.uk/brown/autostitch/autostitch.html)
 See that website for links to commercial versions - but the free version may do what you want.

[**Here is one of several impressive demonstrations**](http://www.cs.bath.ac.uk/brown/panogallery/wedgemount.html) - zoom right out and use cursor keys to rotate continually or tilt vertically.

Also look at possibly using a mirrorball type lens such as [Heather discussed recently in this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22125/how-can-i-prevent-blurred-images-when-using-a-tripod/23471#23471) - [NOT a duplicate btw]

End result looks much better than what you see here.

Comment: Hugin is a very good and free (GPL) stitching software

Answer (score 2):

The expensive option is to use a full frame sensor camera (Canone EOS 5D for example) with a wide lens ( Canon EF 14mm L  or a Canon 16-35mm L for flexibility). This combination provides a very good image quality and fast results.

The cheap way is to use what ever lens/camera you have (Canon EOS 60D with a Canon efs 10-22mm, this should look like a 16mm lens on full frame) with a panorama tripod mount that alows the camera to spin around the lens optical center. That way the images will stich with minimal distorsion. The image quality depends on camera/lens and the software you use to stich the images.

Answer (score 0):

I think, 10mm lens for APS-C should be enough for room shots. Here sample (skip image quality, this is just sample for 10mm in APS-C)
[image]

You can see whole room here and lines still ok, however you can improve it in post porcess still. Point of view should be lower here.

Answer (score 0):

20 to 24mm is the best. Not so wide as to distort the scene and wide enough to represent the whole space. I do architectural work and I love mixing telephoto and wide in the portfolio. The 80mm - 100mm lens will give nice straight lines which play into the strength of of the geometry of the architecture.