# Buying a camera specifically for wide angle photographs

Tags: wide-angle, real-estate

I am a real estate agent. My only need for the camera that I purchase, is to have the best wide angle photos. I was looking at DSLR and point and shoot cameras. What is the best point and shoot camera (i'm not sure if this is the correct term, I'm speaking of something like the canon coolpix)? Also, are there some cheaper options for DSLR cameras with the attachments? I saw a canon ef-s 10-18mm that was priced pretty well but I don't know what kind of camera I would need to attach this to. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: Product recommendation is off-topic here. "best" doesn't exist in general, you are the sole factor determining this rarely achieved equilibrium between cost, technicality, and user experience. So it is also opinion-based (yes... also off-topic here). You should probably look at the following question : [What equipment is necessary/preferred for real estate photography?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8204/what-equipment-is-necessary-preferred-for-real-estate-photography)

Comment: my main question more or less would be, are there any fair priced compact digital cameras that are capable of wide angle lens shots? I read that 18mm is best for real estate as to not potentially mislead any buyers

Comment: For avoidance of doubt, [the human eye has an angle of view about equivalent to that from a **45 mm** lens](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34640/what-lens-focal-length-most-closely-resembles-the-perspective-of-the-human-eye). By choosing an 18mm lens, you are giving views *much* wider than normal human vision; this is why rooms look so big in real estate photos and certainly does "potentially mislead buyers". I appreciate it's what everyone in the industry does though, but if you really want an accurate representation of a room, you don't want an 18mm lens at all. Rant over :-)

Comment: @chicagorealestate That depends on your definitions of "fair priced", "compact", and "capable".

Comment: @mattdm Also "wide angle" (how wide?).

Comment: Equally important is the capability to capture multiple exposures of the same shot (at least 5) easily in order to create HDR images (it can be done tastefully). Otherwise the images will have too much dynamic range.

Comment: @PhilipKendall On the other hand, the eye/brain system is very good at "stitching" together various parts of a wider scene. The 45mm thing has more to do with the magnification provided by the human eye than the FoV.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments say, you first need to define "wide angle". My guess is that you want a camera that has a viewing angle of more than 90 degrees, but you don't want distortion to keep the walls straight. Then, the keyword you're looking for is "ultra-wide", as opposed to "fisheye" which also covers a wide angle but with strong distortion.

Indeed, a 10-*whatever* mm lens on an APS-C sensor body will do the trick (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_view#Sensor_size_effects_.28.22crop_factor.22.29 for example). You probably want *whatever* to be large enough so that the same camera can be used to take more "normal" pictures.

You probably want reasonable low-light performance too, to get good indoors pictures without a flash, in which case an APS-C DSLR will be better than a typical point-and-shoot camera (the key element is the sensor size).

Most point-and-shoot camera won't go up to real "ultra-wide", but some of them can have a wide-angle adapter which may do the trick too.

You may want to look at hybrid cameras, which get most of the advantages of a DSLR without the mirror. Micro Four Thirds cameras may be a good fit for you.

For examples and arguments, see https://www.slrlounge.com/best-dslr-setup-real-estate-photography/

Answer (score 0):

IANARSE, but I've worked with enough of them and reviewed enough photos of houses, both inside and outside, to know you really do **not** want a wide-angle lens.  External shots should be done w/ normal to long lenses to produce aesthetically pleasing images.

Interior shots will be fine with a 50-mm -class lens, and if you want to show a "wide-angle" shot I would recommend using a camera which supports "panorama" imaging.  The problem with lenses in the "wide-angle" category is the "fisheye" distortion which creeps in.  Not something you want in your sales brochures.

Comment: Ultra-wide does not imply fisheye nor distortion ...

Comment: @MatthieuMoy true 'nuff, but there are easier ways to get panorama.

Comment: I agree to some extent on this, but I would not choose a 50 mm lens. Kit lenses are arround 18-55 mm. Using the 18mm focal distance on an interior a lot of times do makes sense.

Comment: Panorama are a real pain for indoor photography because even a small movement causes a non-negligible paralax. The ability to grab a full room in one shot *is* the easiest way to get such pictures. Maybe not the cheapest, but you can't beat "compose, press button, get the picture".